# Why does profile font color change sometimes on stackoverflow?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow

Hi,

I recognized that on my stackoverflow profile site the font color is different then it was some days ago.

E.g.

```
seen    1 sec ago
```

is now black but was orange some hours ago. Why does it change?

Comment: I've noticed the change too but I figured that it was just a style change that was pushed out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are now all technicolor again; for info, the "hotness" of the color changes with age; a brand new user will be highlit, where-as long-established users will... not. Likewise, someone *actively seen on the site lately* will be highlit.